# WPF Best Resources to develop a Simple Kiosk application

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I am in the process of learning WPF so please keep the answers as basic as possible. I am mediocre with VB.NET and an absolute beginner with WPF.

I am attempting to build a light Catering Kiosk Application using WPF for a Special Needs School. It will have 3/4 tabs at the top for the courses(Starter, Mains, Dessert) depending on the day of the week. Each Tab will change the Menu Options which is a horizontal picture list on the screen. On Selecting a Menu Option, it should populate a picture list on the right hand side of the screen acting as a summary of orders. On pressing the menu option, an audio should play in  the background (Name of the item for visually impaired).

The menu is decided at the beginning of the day by people not very used to PC's so I am considering to build the app to read the days menu from a Directory where 3/4 folder depending on the number of courses for that day. Each Folder would contain Sub Folders with the name of the Menu Item and an Image and Audio File within it.

I am hoping that the Application on Load would check the Directory for how the it is arranged for the day and would populate the contents accordingly.

Some WPF snippets that have caught my eye are :
'itemsControl Class', 'Style Resource'

Thanks for all your responses in advance,

Ajmal

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd just make it a VB app, Windows Forms Application and code the functionality you describe in your post. Use the TabControl for the (Starter, Mains, Dessert). Look at the PictureBox control to show an image on the right side etc. Side note, you working with the special needs kids is quite admirable!